# Passing query result to a textbox control on an access form

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I need help with a textbox field on an Access 2007 form. I'm trying to insert the result of a query into the text box control on the form.  This is used soley as information for the user. The form supplies the query with parameters to get the value. The query works fine and returns the correct result. What I can't seem to figure out is how to pass the query result to the textbox. I’ve tried several different ways but with no luck.

(PS> I know a combo box can do a lookup, however I don’t want the user to have to click the dropdown just to select the value as there can only ever be one value result from the query.) I'm open to suggestions as I'm not a programmer or DB Admin, but I've taking a few classes on Access (enough to be dangerous).

```
Private Sub cbo3_Change()
Me.tbx2 = ("SELECT tbl_Billing.Savings_b FROM tbl_Billing GROUP BY tbl_Billing.UBI_b, tbl_Billing.TaxYr_b, tbl_Billing.TaxPrg_b, tbl_Billing.Savings_b HAVING (((tbl_Billing.UBI_b)=forms!f1_UpBilled!cbo1) And ((tbl_Billing.TaxYr_b)=forms!f1_Upbilled!cbo2) And ((tbl_Billing.TaxPrg_b)=forms!f1_UpBilled!cbo3));")

End Sub
```

Comment: Is the SELECT Query saved as a per-compiled Query? Or you want to do this in run time?

Comment: I'd like to run this in real time. I currently have the query in a SQL Select statement, but I"m happy to save the query as a query object in the DB.

Comment: I think i may have found a solution. Rather than using a textbox, or a combobox, I was able to get a list box to reflect the value. There's probably a better way to do this but incase this helps anyone else. I added the query statement to the listbox RowSource and DefaultValue properties and used an on change event on the prior combobox control to requery the statement.

Comment: As long as you are happy. Just that you know, I have written a solution if you want to know how to do it. Good luck !

Comment: Thanks Paul! I'll look over it and see if it will work for my purposes. I'm not sure if my method is the most efficient and I'm willing to look at other options to achieve my goal.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to do this in run time, you need to do the following, I take the controls you are referring to in this is on the same form.

The very simple and straight forward way to get it done is as follows,

```
Private Sub cbo3_Change()
    Dim tmpRS As DAO.Recordset

    Set tmpRS = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT tbl_Billing.Savings_b FROM tbl_Billing GROUP BY " & _
                                        "tbl_Billing.UBI_b, tbl_Billing.TaxYr_b, tbl_Billing.TaxPrg_b, " & _
                                        "tbl_Billing.Savings_b HAVING ((tbl_Billing.UBI_b = '" & Me.cbo1 & "') And (tbl_Billing.TaxYr_b = '" & Me.cbo2 & "') " & _
                                        "And (tbl_Billing.TaxPrg_b = '" & Me.cbo3 & "'))")
    If tmpRS.RecordCount > 0 Then
        Me.tbx2 = tmpRS.Fields(0)
    Else
        Me.tbx2 = 0
    End If

    Set tmpRS = Nothing
End Sub
```

Just note, I have implied all your combo boxes are returning **String** and the field you are comparing against are **Text** type. If that is not the case, you need to make changes accordingly.