# How do I populate the value of a textbox from my database?

Tags: sql, ms-access, textbox, vba

This is my code that I have so far, I tried looking up the solution to my problem but could not find exactly what I was looking for. I am doing this in Access.

```
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
sSQL = "SELECT Building FROM tblDepartment WHERE Department_ID = 
'" & Me.cboDepartment & "'"
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(sSQL)
Me.txtLocation = rs.Fields(1).Value
```

I also tried this:

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Set db = CurrentDb()
sSQL = "SELECT Building FROM tblDepartment WHERE " _
& "Department_ID = '" & Me.cboDepartment.Value & "'"
Me.txtLocation.Value = db.Execute(sSQL)
```

Third attempt was this:

```
Sub spGetBuilding()
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
sSQL = "SELECT Building FROM tblDepartment WHERE Department_ID = '" & Me.cboDepartment & "'"
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(sSQL)

If rs.RecordCount > 0 Then
    Me.txtLocation = rs.Fields(0).Value
Else
    Me.txtLocation = 0
End If

Set rs = Nothing
End Sub
```

But it returned the error message "Data type mismatch in criteria expression"

I figured out the reason for this error is because some of the values don't contain a value for building. I tried to set the parameter so that the WHERE also included a "AND Building IS NOT NULL" to eliminate get rid of the null values. But the same error is still coming up.

Comment: Which Office Application are you using, Excel? Access? The following [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38196833/multiple-arithmetic-operations-in-vba-userforms/38198479#38198479) might help you regarding populating texbox in VBA.

Comment: What error you got? what is the issue? and what DB you use?

Comment: I updated the information in my answer, but I am using Access.

Comment: Please mention error mesage.

Comment: It says "Expected Function or Variable"

Comment: I think [Passing query result to a textbox control on an access form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30354597/passing-query-result-to-a-textbox-control-on-an-access-form)  is may help in your case!

Comment: what is the datatype of `Department_ID`  and `Me.cboDepartment`? this may mismatch and hence gives error..

Comment: I figured out the reason for this error is because some of the values don't contain a value for building. I tried to set the parameter so that the WHERE also included a "AND Building IS NOT NULL" to eliminate get rid of the null values. But the same error is still coming up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For such a simple task, *DLookup* is much simpler, and it returns a Null if no building is found.

Also, leave out the single quotes as *Department_ID* most likely is numeric:

```
Me!txtLocation.Value = DLookup("Building", "tblDepartment", "Department_ID = " & Me!cboDepartment.Value & "")
```

Answer (score 1):

Most certainly the reason is behind you combobox.
If you are using a combobox with more than 1 column, hiding the column that has an `ID` because you use a query to populate said combobox, **Then** you are passing the underlying ID to the select query.

To actually pass what is written on the combobox to the select clause use it's text property.

```
sSQL = "SELECT Building FROM tblDepartment WHERE " _
& "Department_ID = '" & Me.cboDepartment.Text & "'"
```